# Numerical sequence almost solved

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, sequences-and-series

I need help to sovle this sequence:

**3/6**,  1/2  ,  **3/4/7/6**,   9/14 ,   **3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6**,   245/256, x, x

i get as  result **3/4/4/5/5/5/6/9/8/8/8/7/7/6 and 5/6** but i will exlpain why i don't think this one is right.

I've noticed that this sequence Works like that: 
**3/6**=1/2

**3/4/7/6**=9/14

**3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6**=245/256  So if we find the next x we also find the final x.

Now i've also noticed that in this sequence we add to 3/6 numbers 
in fact 3/6 becomse 3/4/7/6  four comes after 3 and 7 comes after 6 and that's the first number,

now we may think that to get the next number we just need to keep adding numbers and have something like that:**3/4/5/8/7/6** but this one doesn't correspond to the nuber of the sequence, we need to find a way to get 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6,and so I tought that the numbers added before repeats 1 time in this case,by repeating 4 and 7 we get **3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6**  now we need to repeat number 5 and number 8 because they are the numbers we added before, and we get 3/4/4/5/5/5/6/9/8/8/8/7/7/6(I'm repeating 5 and 8 2 times because the pattern goes like that 3/6(+2numbers=3/4/7/6 +4 numbers= 3/4/4/5//8/7/7/6 + 6 numbers= 3/4/4/5/5/5/6/9/8/8/8/7/7).
but I get 5/6 as a result by solving this fraction ,and it doesn't follow the gradual increase in fact 3/6<  **3/4/7/6**  <3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6 but the last one 3/4/4/5/5/5/6/9/8/8/8/7/7/6 isn't bigger than 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6 so it doesn't respect the sequence.

Another solution could be this one: 1st criteria:the numbers we add before just repeat 1 time so we have 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6 then we have something like this: 3/4/4/5/5/6/6/7/9/8/8/7/7/6 that gives 81/49

Or the one given by another user : First one: recursion:
3/4/4/5 **/4/5/5/6/9/8/8/7/** 8/7/7/6
Second one: insert brackets:
(((3/4)/(4/5))/((4/5)/(5/6)))/(((9/8)/(8/7))/((8/7)/(7/6)))=1000/1029

Comment: What does 3/4/4/5/5/5/6/9/8/8/8/7/7/6 mean?  Are all the slashes meant to indicate division?  If so, you have to tell us the order of operations -- division is not associative.  I can't make head or tail of this question.

Comment: Yes the slashes indicate division, the division should be made in this order: let's say we have 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6 we need to to (3/4)/(4/5)/(8/7)/(7/6) that becomes ((3/4*5/4))/((8/7*6/7))=15/16/48/49=15/16*49/48=735/768=245/256 @saulspatz

Comment: What is "this order"?

Comment: i edited my comment @saulspatz

Comment: Need your help @David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the answer I was thinking of already, but here are my thoughts. Unfortunately, with sequence problems like these the rules to generate them may not be unique, unless the sequence given is so long as to eliminate all ambiguity.

The first thing I see is that

> 3/4/7/6 is not 9/14. In fact 3/4/7/6 = 1/56.
> 9/14 = (3/4)/(7/6)

Same with

> 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6. You need to break it down like this: ((3/4)/(4/5))/((8/7)/(7/6))

As you can see

> the term is broken down in half and each half is then broken down in half again. This leads me to believe that your solution will not work anyway, because you can’t break down the term you found in this way. Actually, I don’t even know how it is that you are finding the division exactly...

Also notice how

> the division term grows: 2, 4, 8. You interpreted that as +2, +4, +6, but I think it’s *2 all the way.

The pattern I see is:

> a/b
> a/a+1/b+1/b = a/b/c/d
> a/a+1/b/b+1/c+1/c/d+1/d = a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h
> a/a+1/b/b+1/c/c+1/d/d+1/e+1/e/f+1/f/g+1/g/h+1/h

The next term will then be:

> 3/4/4/5/4/5/5/6/9/8/8/7/8/7/7/6 and the next (((3/4)/(4/5))/((4/5)/(5/6)))/(((9/8)/(8/7))/((8/7)/(7/6))) = 1000/1029

Comment: @jackien These values are already given in the problem 3/4/4/5/8/7/7/6 = a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h

Comment: basically the variables change everytime right? but they follow everytime the patter,thank you alot

Comment: Do you have a contact,i would like to talk you in private,everything is ok for me(skype,steam,facebook,discord,etc)